# Creating LineString geometry from Point geometries with Python's OSGEO/OGR library

Tags: python, point, ogr, linestring, osgeo

Is it possible to create a `LineString` object with Python's `osgeo`/`ogr` library starting from multiple `Point` objects?

For example, I know from [the Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-a-multilinestring) that I can create a `MultiLineString` by adding multiple `LineString` objects:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

multiline = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString)

line1 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line1.AddPoint_2D(1214242.4174581182, 617041.9717021306)
line1.AddPoint_2D(1234593.142744733, 629529.9167643716)
multiline.AddGeometry(line1)

line2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line2.AddPoint_2D(1184641.3624957693, 626754.8178616514)
line2.AddPoint_2D(1219792.6152635587, 606866.6090588232)
multiline.AddGeometry(line2)

print(multiline.ExportToWkt())
```

However, when I use this idea to create a `LineString` from multiple `Point` geometries, it doesn't work:

```py
from osgeo import ogr 

coords_p1 = [1214242.4174581182, 617041.9717021306]
coords_p2 = [1234593.1427447330, 629529.9167643716]

pt1 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
pt1.AddPoint_2D(*coords_p1)

pt2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
pt2.AddPoint_2D(*coords_p2)

line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddGeometry(pt1)
line.AddGeometry(pt2)
```

When I try to run the snippet above, it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\diasf\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_43960/3403084045.py", line 11, in
>
> line.AddGeometry(pt1)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 6245, in AddGeometry
>
> return _ogr.Geometry_AddGeometry(self, *args)
>
> RuntimeError: OGR Error: Unsupported geometry type

I know the snippet above would work if I used `line.AddPoint(*coords_p1)` instead of `line.AddGeometry(pt1)` (i.e., it works if I pass each point's coordinates to the `LineString` object instead of trying to add the actual `Point` geometries).

But is there a way to build `LineString`s out of `Point` geometries, or is this just not possible?

Comment: You're doing exactly that in the first example using `line.AddPoint()`.  It looks to be failing because you're trying to use `line.AddGeometry()` instead in the second example

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of the question (pun marginally intended =P). I don't want to pass the *coordinates* of the points to the `LineString` object. I want to, instead, pass the `Point` geometries themselves. Note how in the first example, there is a statement that says `multiline.AddGeometry(line2)`. Here, I am adding a `LineString` geometry to another `MultiLineString` object. I want to know if it is possible to do something analogous, but adding `Point` geometries to a `LineString` geometry. Sorry if I wasn't very clear in my original question.

Comment: I should also mention that, in the second example, I tried two different approaches: `line.AddGeometry(pt1)` and `line.AddPoint(pt1)`. Sadly, both failed.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I glossed over that detail.  I'm not aware of a way short of unpacking the coords, as you're aiming to avoid.  `AddGeometry()` only seems to be meant for use on geoms of type `wkbGeometryCollection`.  But you could at least unpack them from the point objects themselves if you don't have access to the original coords, with `line.AddPoint(*pt1.GetPoint())` or whatever

Comment: You may have reasons for sticking with GDAL/OGR, but consider using shapely for a more Pythonic interface if not

Comment: Yeah, I very much prefer using shapely, but I just want to get the hang of using GDAL/OGR because Shapely sadly doesn't work well with M-value geometries, which I have to manipulate quite often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@mikewatt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64255/mikewatt), it seems like I cannot add a point geometry directly. The best I can do is use the `GetPoint` or `GetPoint_2D` methods and pass the `Point` geometry's coordinates to the `LineString` geometry, as shown below:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

coords_p1 = [1214242.4174581182, 617041.9717021306]
coords_p2 = [1234593.1427447330, 629529.9167643716]

pt1 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
pt1.AddPoint_2D(*coords_p1)
print(pt1.ExportToWkt())
#POINT (1214242.41745812 617041.971702131)

pt2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
pt2.AddPoint_2D(*coords_p2)
print(pt2.ExportToWkt())
#POINT (1234593.14274473 629529.916764372)

line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)

line.AddPoint_2D(*pt1.GetPoint_2D())
line.AddPoint_2D(*pt2.GetPoint_2D())

print(line.ExportToIsoWkt())
# LINESTRING (1214242.41745812 617041.971702131,1234593.14274473 629529.916764372)
```